# How to update fields properly with redux elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, mern

thank you in advance for any and all help :) .

I am currently going crazy trying to finish my cart system, trying to do two operations that seem to be extremely easy but for some reason the basic programming logic does not work when it comes to redux ( which means I am doing something very wrong ).

First, I'll introduce the structure of the redux cart

```js
  name: "carrinho",
  initialState: {
    produtos: [],
    quantidade: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
```

well the two operations are ->
1 - exclude a `produtos` from my `carrinho` redux

my approach was this :
inside the "Cart.jsx" page I have a button that passes as parameters the unique id of the product variation I want to delete, as well as the final price that will be decremented in the cart total price

```js
      <button onClick={() => {
         const id = produto.variacoes.map((item) => item.id_variacao)
         const quantidade_comprada = produto.variacoes.map((item) => item.quantidade)
         const preco = produto.preco
         
  
         gerirDeletarProduto({
           id:id,
           totalPrice: preco + quantidade_comprada,
         })
                        
       }}>delete</button>
```

`gerirDeletarProduto` calls the function `excluirProduto` inside the reducer that looks like this

```js
    excluirProduto : (estado_anterior, action) => {
      estado_anterior.quantidade -= 1;
      estado_anterior.produtos = estado_anterior.produtos.filter( (item) => item.id_variacao_root !== action.id);
      estado_anterior.total -= action.totalPrice;

    },
```

the result of this code should be a simple decrement of the general quantity of items in my cart, which works fine, but the next line that should be responsible for returning all the elements that don't have the unique id of the product variation that I want to exclude doesn't work, I simply continue with all the products and I don't know what to do about it.

The second operation is ->

2- decrement the `quantidade` inside `produtos` and also decrement the `quantidade_comprada` inside `variacoes`.

the product structure looks like this:

```
produtos: Array(2)
0:
id_variacao_root: "6207992d31efd1289324d948"
preco: 35
quantidade: 5 **// THIS IS THE ONE THAT NEEDS TO BE DECREMENTED (this one is easier and i can make it work)**
titulo: "gorrinho dahora60"
variacoes: Array(1)
0:
cor: "Roxo"
id_variacao: "6207992d31efd1289324d948"
quantidade_atual: 88
quantidade_comprada: 5 **// THIS IS THE ONE THAT PLAGUES MY DREAMS WHEN I GO TO SLEEP AND I CAN'T IN ANY WAY ACCESS IT TO DECREMENT IT TOGETHER WITH THE OTHER QUANTITY**
quantidade_depois_compra: 83
tamanho: "4M"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
__v: 0
_id: "6207992d31efd1289324d945"
```

well, my approaches to try to solve this problem were the following (as in the first operation I pass the unique id of the variation that I want to decrement aswell as the price and quantity )

```js
    atualizarProduto: (state, { payload }) => {
      
      state.produtos = state.produtos.map((product) => 

      product.id_variacao_root === payload.id 
        ? { ...product, quantidade:   payload.quantidade + product.quantidade}
        : product
        )
      state.total += payload.quantidade < 1 ? -payload.preco : payload.preco
      
      
    },
```

```js
    atualizarQuantidadeDepoisDaCompra: (state, { payload }) => {
      
      state.produtos.variacoes = state.produtos.variacoes.map((product) => 

      product.id_variacao === payload.id
      ? product.quantidade_depois_compra =   payload.quantidade + product.quantidade
      : product
      
      
      )
    },
```

Well that's it, thanks again if you got this far, it would mean the world to me to solve this problem, any doubt or change do not hesitate to talk to me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what is not specific about it and this is really not enough detail?